# Reading star schema data files from SQL database

Tags: database, dataformat

We have data files from (what I understand to be) star schema SQL database. The database has 5 different files with extensions `.hed .chr .idx .inf .tad`. I am looking for a way to read these files and load the content into something else (that could be anything for now).

Does anyone have an idea where to start?

Answer (score 0):

This a Ac Nelson star database, I am afraid that the only way I know is to open it with

**In Fact**

After that you choose the data you want use along the various dimensions, and then save it as flat excel file, now you will be able to process it using Python, R, Excel.